# Get data from joined table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Please check the image.

[image: two table, fevorite table and post table.]

Here i have 2 table. One is **post** table and another is **fevorite** table. Both has primary key and `post_id` is FOREIGN_KEY in **fevorite** table.

**Now my needs are**:

1. Select post_id list from fevorite table WHERE fevorite_by=2.
2. Using this post_id list get post details (post_title,created_by, ...) from post table.

I need all of those things in single query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add a comment before giving a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sub query to get your result:

```
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE post_id IN (
SELECT post_id FROM fevorite WHERE fevorite_by = 2)
```

Or you can do it by JOIN

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Post P
JOIN fevorite F ON F.post_id = P.post_id
WHERE F.fevorite_by = 2
```